# Trying to access variables while scraping website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm currently trying to scrape a website (url in code below), however when I pull out the section of html I'm looking to work with, all I get is the variable name of the information I'm looking for. The actual value for the variable is present when I manually inspect the page's html but I assume when I scrape the page that all I see is the website referencing the variable from elsewhere.

I'm hoping someone can help me try to access this information. I have tried just scraping the website's html using selenium, however I seem just get back the same html that I scrape when using requests (maybe I'm doing it incorrectly and somebody can show me the correct approach).

This is a refined version of my code:

```
import scrapy #For scraping
from scrapy import Selector
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
           'Referer': 'https://google.com',
           'DNT': '1'}

url = 'https://groceries.aldi.ie/en-GB/drinks/beer-ciders'
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
sel = Selector(text=html)
x  = sel.xpath('//*[@id="vueSearchResults"]/div//span')#/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/span/span

print((x.extract())[8])
```

This then returns the following:

```
<span>{{Product.ListPrice}}</span>
```

From which I want to get the actual value of 'Product.ListPrice'. I'd appreciate it if some can point me in the right direction as to accessing this variable's information, or a way to scrape the website's html - as seen by a user traversing the webpage.
** It was recommended to me to send a POST request through this API: 'https://groceries.aldi.ie/api/product/calculatePrices' along with passing request headers and payload, but I'm not entirely sure how to pull this off (I'm new to this aspect of scraping), if someone could provide me an example of how to carry this out I'd greatly appreciate it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can replicate the `POST` request through Scrapy.

**Code**

```
import scrapy
import json

class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    headers = {
        "authority": "groceries.aldi.ie",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
        "accept-language": "en-GB",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36",
        "websiteid": "a763fb4a-0224-4ca8-bdaa-a33a4b47a026",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "origin": "https://groceries.aldi.ie",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "referer": "https://groceries.aldi.ie/en-GB/drinks/beer-ciders?sortDirection=asc&page=1"
    }

    body = '{"products":["4088600284026","5391528370382","5391528372836","5391528372850","5391528372874","4088600298696","4088600103709","4088600388700","5035766046028","5000213021934","4088600012551","4088600325934","4088600300153","25389111","4072700001171","4088600012537","4088600012544","4088600013138","4088600013145","4088600103525","4088600103532","4088600103570","4088600103600","4088600135182","4088600141848","4088600142050","4088600158105","4088600217024","4088600217208","4088600241302","4088600249292","4088600249308","4088600280615","4088600281445","4088600283043","4088600284088","4088600295688","4088600295800","4088600295817","4088600303925"]}'

    def start_requests(self):
       url = 'https://groceries.aldi.ie/api/product/calculatePrices'
       yield scrapy.Request(url=url,method='POST', headers=self.headers,body=self.body)

    def parse(self,response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        for i in data.get('ProductPrices'):
            print('Listing price is', i.get('ListPrice'),'\t','Unit Price is',i.get('UnitPrice') )
```

**Output(Truncated)**

```
Listing price is €4.19   Unit Price is €4.23
Listing price is €1.99   Unit Price is €3.98
Listing price is €1.99   Unit Price is €3.98
Listing price is €1.99   Unit Price is €3.98
Listing price is €1.99   Unit Price is €3.98
```

Comment: Hi Shivam, this seems to be what I'm looking for, but could you explain what's going on in your code a little bit and how to use it? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, I am sending a POST request through API which requires headers & body. After sending successful requests the server returns the JSON response. At last, iterating through JSON to get the values. Please don't forget to accept & upvote if it helped you.

Comment: Ok awesome, thanks! Don't worry I'll do that now.

Comment: Is the object being yielded in the start_requests function meant to be the response variable in the parse function?

Comment: That's correct. You are sending the Request to the server in start_requests function and then collecting the response in parse function.

Comment: I'm actually having difficulty getting any output from the for loop in the parse function, it's giving me 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'. Does the code give you the correct output? And if so how are you calling the class?

Comment: Yes for me it's giving correct result. Can you check the body by using print(response.body) in parse function. Please also refer to the truncated output which I am getting. It's simple by just using scrapy crawl test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235226/discussion-between-oxin-and-shivam).